# Временная шкала на чистом JavaScript и Svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, timeline

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже задавал похожий вопрос, но как оказалось мне нужно реализовать данный график на чистом js.
С чего начать? Я в основном видел примеры для canvas, но как работать с svg не смог найти.

Comment: jquery не особо нужен, необходимо просто составить длинную строку программно

Comment: Про jquery мне сказали в дополнение, а так хорошо бы все на чистом js написать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно нарисовать некоторое количество прямоугольников и линий, все они описываются определенными тегами, в примере ниже элементы `rect` описывают прямоугольники, `path` - линии, а `text` - подписи. Все это собрано в одну  большую строку, которая, собственно, и описывает `svg` изображение. Смотрите результирующий текст HTML, через отладчик.

```js
let data = [...Array((Math.random()*100)|0)]
    .map(_ => Math.random());

let total = data.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);

let a = 0;
data = data.map(i => ({
  x: a,
  w: a+=i*100/total,
  c: Math.random()*360
}));

data = data.map(d => `<rect 
  fill=hsl(${d.c},55%,55%)
  y=10 
  height=30 
  x=${d.x} 
  width=${d.w}></rect>`);

let ticks = [...Array(5)]
.map((_,i)=>1+i)
.map(i=>`
  <text font-size="5" x=${i/6*100} y=5 text-anchor=middle>${i*4+':00'}</text>
  <path d='m${i/6*100},7v3' stroke=red></path> `);


document.body.innerHTML += `<svg width=300px height=200px viewbox="0 0 100 66">
 ${data+ticks}
</svg>`;
```

Comment: **как-то так** - это очень модно сейчас? Думаю на сайте много поклонников твоего творчества и очень хотелось бы хоть кратких комментарий в основных моментах решения (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я писал это с телефона, буду у компа - что то прокомментирую

Comment: а что код легче писать, чем комментарии к нему? :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT получается что так

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  ***что то прокомментирую*** :)))  (+)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Спасибо  большое очень помогли!!!